# Persist commands typed to GRUB rescue

Tags: grub2

After deleting old Linux partitions in order to free space on hard disk, I got an error from GRUB:

> error: no such partition

And then I saw a `grub rescue>` prompt. After googling around I found that in order to boot normally I have to type the following commands.

```
set prefix=(hd0,msdos5)/boot/grub
set root=(hd0,msdos5)
insmod /boot/grub/linux.mod
linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda5 ro
initrd /initrd.img
boot
```

[Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/782797/) is the boot info summary report created by Boot-Repair.

However, on each reboot I have to type this again. How can I tell to GRUB once and all what configuration file to use?

Comment: I have the exact same problem, however when I try to use `insmod` I'm prompted with `error: unknown filesystem.`. When I `ls` I'm presented with `(hd0) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1)`. I've tried setting either of these as `prefix` and then `root` but whenever I try to `insmod` I'm prompted with the same `error: unknown filesystem.`. What can I do?

Comment: @PolyShell I think you better ask this as a separate question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try these commands

```
sudo update-grub
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

If you want a graphical option, try [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Previously I was running Boot-Repair from a liveCD and it didn't helped, and after I've found what commands to type in `grub rescue` I haven't tried it once again. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run `update-grub` to update /boot/grub/grub.cfg?