# Frequent grub rescue error: unknown filesystem

Tags: 12.04, 10.04, grub2, grubrescue

It's really frustrating.

## Three week's back story:

I faced the following error on `ubuntu 10.04 LTS Desktop`,

```
error : unknown filesystem
grub rescue>
```

I tried many solutions online apart from [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119597/grub-rescue-error-unknown-filesystem) and [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90471/persist-commands-typed-to-grub-rescue) and eventually I could not boot my system at all. Trying those solutions could not completely fix it and then I had to face `initramfs`(could not remember exact error).

As I could not fix, a week back I did a fresh install of `Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop` and after a week i.e, now, I got the same `grub rescue>` error. Could anybody tell me what's the reason behind this error?. Is there any problem with the Ubuntu or it's a problem at my side due to some reason?.

My machine description:

I have two hard disks, windows is installed on one hard disk and on another it's Ubuntu. I installed the operating systems(vista, ubuntu) such a way one is not known to another, I mean to say, I'll unplug one hard disk and install the Ubuntu and similarly I'll unplug the ubuntu hard disk, installed the vista on another hard disk,  generally I do(I actually don't want to run into grub/boot.ini issues installing OSs connecting both the hard disks). When ever I power on the computer windows will boot by default, and I'll generally boot to ubuntu by pressing `F8` and selecting the ubuntu hard disk.

Any help is greatly appreciated!. Thank you!

Comment: Anybody ever resolved?

Comment: I myself closed it as I cannot replicate the problem!

Answer (score 1):

may be one of the harddisk got some bad sectors, try to run them separately , if it always happens with the secondary hdd where ubuntu resides may be the hdd has gone bad.
if you don't think the hdd is bad , give more details about parttions on both the disks and also the type of boot efi or normal.

you can attach a screenshot of gparted or disk utility for both the disks.

Answer (score 0):

this is probably what you are looking for:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Troubleshooting
good luck

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.