# Installed Ubuntu 10.04 on USB - Now I need it on an HDD

Tags: installation, server, 10.04, lts

I'm undoubtedly a newbie in all this.  After reading so many reviews and pushed by a moody pogoplug set up at home (for backing up data and streaming of files), I tried to make my laptops and ipad become reliant on a brand new HP N36L Microserver (AMD Athlon Core Duo, 8GB Ram), 2x2TB WD20EARX HDDs and one Kingston SVP200S3/120G 120 GB,Internal SSD to act as the main booting drive.

Unsurprisingly, I got it all wrong.  My Ubuntu installed and runs only from the USB drive I had previously used to install from.  And my server can be seen on my home network, but could not be accessed despite the repeated attempts.  Most probably I might need to install again?  Where did I go wrong in all this?

I get the server going through bios then stops with error:

```
error: no such device: 00eaf4-933e-4895-ae66-2f4a44c92fc. grub rescrue>
```

[The boot-repair info file is included.](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5586133/)

**Update**

[New boot-repair info and log after installing GRUB on `/sda` and running boot-repair.](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5589679)

Please help (this really sounds like an SOS out of a stricken ship in a perfect storm).

Thanks

Comment: Wait. You literally installed Ubuntu on USB? Or use the Live version?

Comment: @user68186: Tried Bootrepair... no deal.

Comment: @Melon:  Yep... I used the Ubuntu 10.04.4_NetInstall_64 to make a bootable USB.  I guess that's the mistake?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more, by editing the question, what you did and what exactly happens when you boot from the USB.

Comment: @user68186:  thanks for coming back.  I get the server going through bios then stops with error: "error: no such device: 00eaf4-933e-4895-ae66-2f4a44c92fc.  grub rescrue>"

Comment: It looks like the bootloader GRUB can't find the rest of the program, that should be in the SSD or HDD. See the accepted answer to http://askubuntu.com/questions/90471/persist-commands-typed-to-grub-rescue . Create the bootinfo summary using boot-repair. upload it at http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/ and add the link to your question. This will help others understand whats going on.

Comment: @user68186:  Thanks indeed for interest and request.  Here's the boot-repair summary to help you understand my mess:  http://paste.ubuntu.com/5586133/

Comment: I am not skilled enough to figure this one out quite yet. It seems you have a 16GB USB(?) drive and another 2GB USB drive plugged in. Try these two commands `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` and then `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: @user68186:  Thanks indeed for kind advice - which I will try later today.  Yes I have two USB drives plugged in:  the 16GB is the one where my Ubuntu is install whereas the 2GB was in the process of being burned with a new fresh install copy of Ubuntu 10.04.4k.  Thanks for any tips

Comment: @user68186:  Followed your advice.  Grub install completed without errors.  Grub update reported "Could not find /boot/grub/menu.lst file.  Would  you like /boot/grub/menu.lst generated for you? Y/N".  I confirmed request and reported:

Found Grub 2:  /boot/grub/core.img
Found kernel:  /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found kernel:  /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-45-generic
Found GRUB 2:  /boot/grub/core.img
Found kernel:  /boot/memtest86+.bin
Updating /boot/grub/menu.lst ... done

On Booting I get GRUB Loading stage 1.5
GRUB Loading, please wait...
Error 21.

That is where the booting stops.
Any advice?

Comment: @user68186:  Following the previous action, I tried boot repair.  The good news is that I got a log of the actions as well as an output from boot repair. The bad news is that on booting the system, booting stops with error "Missing operating system." message. (see http://paste.ubuntu.com/5589679)

Comment: You may have to reinstall Ubuntu in `/sda`.

Comment: @user68186:  thanks... that's what I'll do later this week as am away.  Thanks for advice anyway.